# Why doesn't the doctor fix the chameleon circuit of the Tardis?

Tags: doctor-who

I'm aware that on the odd occasion it has changed into a cylinder, and ornamental dresser for example, but why doesn't The Doctor get round to fixing the chameleon circuit of the Tardis?

I presume the Doc likes it, but as he has the time to fix it, why doesn't he ever get round to fixing it once and for all?

Comment: He doesn't know how. Doctor-Donna does, but passes out before telling him.

Comment: Have you seen this question? [How Did the Chameleon Circuit Break](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/25155/how-did-the-chameleon-circuit-break)

Comment: sipp- yes but he has the time on his hands, plus surely as each doctor has his (so far) own tastes, the chances are that one since Tom B would have had enough and have a go in earnest. I know nothing is sacred (e.g. "but a Darlek *can't* climb stairs!) so how come the writers seem to think this is.

Comment: In the few attempts he’s tried, it hasn’t gone well. That would probably put him off trying again. And I guess he’s grown to like it, over the years.

Comment: @Fetchezlavache I only mention it because I thought the answer to it fit the question. There's a comment about rule #1 the Doctor lies. I think its a good thing to consider. He probably just doesn't know how, or as it is pointed out in the modern series he's grown to like the Police Box. Good question though, +1 from me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He tried that on Logopolis, and it didn't end well.

In the programme Logopolis - the last Tom Baker programme - the Logopolitans used block transfer computation that could reset the chameleon circuit, but the Master used Adric to enter some new numbers making the TARDIS shrink.

Whilst fighting the Master the Doctor fell off a radio telescope causing him to regenerate. And the Master escaped, but left Adric behind.

Comment: He also tried in "The Attack of the Cybermen" and was semi-successful, but the Tardis was "out of practice" and chose odd shapes that didn't blend into its surroundings like a pipe organ, and eventually it reverted back to a police box (I don't think it was really explained why it went back to its old shape though).

Comment: I have got to watch Logopolis one of these days.

Comment: It is good programme, and features a regeneration.

Comment: @Hypnosifi, IIRC, he removed the fix.